# How to create a user and a lot of her files with Puppet?

Tags: puppet

I need to create a user account and a lot of files for that user with Puppet.

Works fine with the most straightforward approach, but on every `file` resource I have to specify `owner => 'theuser'`, which seems horribly redundant (if I don't they end up root-owned).

Is there a way to have a scoped default for the owner? Or something like sudo where puppet runs under that user for a certain set of resources?

Comment: are all the files in the same location?

Comment: @Mike: a common root folder could be arranged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if everything is in a single location you can use the `recurse` option for file

```
file { "/path/to/files/":
    ensure  => directory,
    recurse => true,
    owner   => "user",
    group   => "group",
    mode    => "700",
    source  => "puppet:///modules/moduleName/path/in/files/",
  }
```

Then just have all your files in like

modules/ModuleName/path/in/files/

Puppet will put all the files in that module path into /path/to/files on the system owned by that user/group.

Comment: Will it do anything to files that are already in that directory (but not in the module)?

Comment: if any filename matches it will overwrite them.. you can add a `purge   => true,` to it and it will delete any file on the system that isn't in puppet for that directory

Comment: Sweet. That cuts down not just on the `owner` attribute, but on the multiple file resources altogether. Can this also be made to work with files that are not static, but use `content => Template(` somehow (some files in that module are templates)?

Comment: if it can work with templates.. i don't know of a way

Answer (score 1):

To cut down on e.g. the `owner` attribute you can add some defaults.

```
File {
  owner => 'user',
  group => 'somegroup',
  mode  => '0444'
}

file {
  '/some/where/file1': source => 'some-source1';
  '/some/where/file2': source => 'some-source2';
  '/some/where/file3': source => 'some-source3';
}
```

Documentation on resource defaults:
https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_defaults.html

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for this default definition feature?

Comment: @Thilo I added a link to the official documentation about it in the answer.